# Windows bat save output based on unc path

Tags: windows, for-loop, path, cmd, unc

I am working on batch script, I want to get something from many shares for example \\server\share  and the save the output to something like __server_share.txt

Any suggestion on how to save the output in a loop? 
It's a very big list of shares that is why I want to do it through a loop.

Comment: Explain your task a little more thoroughly please.  Do you want to read text files and append them all into one file?

Comment: I want to read a file which contains a list of UNC paths, 
It will have to generate a filename for each UNC path, a new file.

Comment: Where will the new files be saved?  Locally, or one on each server?

Answer (score 0):

If "shares.lst" contains shares in the form

```
\\server1\share
\\server2\share
\\server3\share
```

I tried this batch command:

```
FOR /F %%s IN (shares.lst) DO (ECHO %%s >>result.txt & TYPE %%s\something >>result.txt)
```

and the "result.txt" was

```
\\server1\share
Contents of something on server1.
\\server2\share
Contents of something on server2.
\\server3\share
Contents of something on server3.
```

Or, if you really need each result in separate file, this works:

```
 FOR /F %%s IN (shares.lst) DO CALL :SERVER %%s
 GOTO :EOF
:SERVER
 SET UNC=%1
 TYPE %1\something>>%UNC:\=_%.txt
```